# Different user.config file when application is running as scheduled task

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user.config

I have an application that is using a settings file, and when it is running as ascheduled task, it uses another user.setting file than when im debugging the application through Visual Studio.
Is this normal behaviour?

user.config from VS debugging `appname.vshos_StrongName_ldr4uvycmc51wccs12nto50cvy3vujt3`
user.config from Scheduled task `appname.exe_Url_5fnquv0g1secc1miglozdookwwdastgw`

I want the same user.config in both cases! Do I need to make a custom settings file (simple textfile) and read and write to that, or how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal: when debugging the config file for yourapp_vshost.exe is used which is clearly a different exe, so has a different config.

A simple solution is to create a link from one file to the other:

```
mklink first/path/user.config second/path/user.config
```

you might have to use `mklink /H` if the app isn't happy with it.

Or first start your exe without debugging, then attach to it.

Or deselect `Enable the Visual Studio hosting process` in your project's config, which will get rid of the yourapp_vshost.exe (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx) to check if you need it. Bascially you don't if you don't use the designer..)